# __sync_bool_compare_and_swap with different parameter types in Cython

Tags: multithreading, function, cython

I am using Cython for fast parallel processing of data, adding items to a shared memory linked list from multiple threads. I use __sync_bool_compare_and_swap, which provides an atomic compare and swap (CAS) operation to compare if the value was not modified (by another thread) before replacing it with a new value.

```
cdef extern int __sync_bool_compare_and_swap (void **ptr, void *oldval, void *newval) nogil

cdef bint firstAttempt = 1
cdef type *next = NULL
cdef type *newlink = ....

while firstAttempt or not __sync_bool_compare_and_swap( <void**> c, <void*>next, <void*>newlink):
    firstAttempt = 0
    next = c[0]
    newlink.next = next
```

This works very well. However, now I also want to keep track of the size of the linked list, and want to use the same CAS function for the updates, however, this time it is not pointers that need to be updated but an int. How can use the same external function twice in Cython, once with void** parameter and once with an int* parameter?

EDIT

What I have in mind is two separate atomic operations, in one atomic operation I want to update the linked list, in the other I want to update the size. You can do it in C, but for Cython it means you have to reference the same external function twice with different parameters, can that be done?

CONCLUSION

The answer suggested by DavidW works. In case anyone is thinking to use a similar construction, you should be aware that when using two separate update functions there is no guarantee these are processed in sequence (i.e. another thread can update in between), however, if the objective is to update a cumulative value for instance to monitor progress while multithreading or to create an aggregated result that is not used until all threads are finished, CAS does guarantee that all updates are done exactly once. Unexpectedly, gcc refuses to compile without casting to void*, so either define separate hard-typed versions, or you need to cast. A snippet from my code:

in some_header.h:

```
#define sync_bool_compare_and_swap_int __sync_bool_compare_and_swap
#define sync_bool_compare_and_swap_vp __sync_bool_compare_and_swap
```

in some_prog.pxd:

```
cdef extern from "some_header.h":
    cdef extern int sync_bool_compare_and_swap_vp (void **ptr, void *oldval, void *newval) nogil
    cdef extern int sync_bool_compare_and_swap_int (int *ptr, int oldval, int newval) nogil
```

in some_prog.pyx:

```
cdef void updateInt(int *value, int incr) nogil:
    cdef cINT previous = value[0]
    cdef cINT updated = previous + incr

    while not sync_bool_compare_and_swap_int( c, previous, updated):
        previous = value[0]
        updated = previous + incr
```

Comment: That's plain impossible to do without a lock if you want the data to be consistent. that would involve atomically changing data at two completely different memory locations. Doesn't seem like it'd be useful to have anyhow though. What's your actual use case?

Comment: @Voo added some clarity to the question, these can be two separate atomic operations, the problem is how to reference the same external function twice in Cython with different parameters?

Comment: Fair enough, the problem is that those aren't really "functions". They're built-ins that behave similar to a function. I see only the two obvious workarounds: link a c dll that forwards the calls or put the definitions into separate modules.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So the issue (as I understand it) is that it's `__sync_bool_compare_and_swap` is a compiler intrinsic rather than a function, so doesn't really have a fixed signature, because the compiler just figures it out. However, Cython demands to know the types, and because you want to use it with two different types, you have a problem.

I can't see a simpler way than  resorting to a (very) small amount of C to "help" Cython. Create a header file with a bunch of `#defines`

```
/* compare_swap.h */
#define sync_bool_compare_swap_voidp __sync_bool_compare_and_swap
#define sync_bool_compare_swap_int __sync_bool_compare_and_swap
```

You can then tell Cython that each of these is a separate function

```
cdef extern from "compare_swap.h":
    int sync_bool_compare_swap_voidp(void**, void*, void*)
    int sync_bool_compare_swap_int(int*, int, int)
```

At this stage you should be able to use them naturally as plain functions without any type casting (i.e. no `<void**>` in your code, since this tends to hide real errors). The C preprocessor will generate the code you want and all is well.

---

**Edit**: Looking at this a few years later I can see a couple of simpler ways you could probably use (untested, but I don't see why they shouldn't work). First you could use Cython's ability to map a name to a "cname" to avoid the need for an extra header:

```
cdef extern from *:
    int sync_bool_compare_swap_voidp(void**, void*, void*) "__sync_bool_compare_and_swap"
    int sync_bool_compare_swap_int(int*, int, int) "__sync_bool_compare_and_swap"
```

Second (and probably best) you could use a single generic definition (just telling Cython that it's a varargs function):

```
cdef extern from "compare_swap.h":
    int __sync_bool_compare_and_swap(...)
```

This way Cython won't try to understand the types used, and will just defer it entirely to C (which is what you want).

---

I wouldn't like to comment on whether it's safe for you to use two atomic operations like this, or whether that will pass through a state with dangerously inconsistent data....

Comment: Thank you @DavidW, this seems to be required to make it work. You are right to raise concerns for the danger of working with inconsistent data, however, for tracking progress or computing a result that is not used until after all threads are finished, this should be fine.

Comment: @jeroen the cost of the atomic operations is likely to be higher than iterating once through the list after you're finished then.